# How Can I Show The Top Rows Those cover 50% Of the Total Visitor in SQL

Tags: sql

**Problem:** I want to fetch a set of data from a table related to search keyword metrics. I want to fetch only the keywords that cover 50% of the total unique visitors. The overall code is given below -

```
  SELECT  se_keyword
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT visitor_id) AS Distinct_Visitors
FROM    search_table
WHERE   DATE >= '20210207'
GROUP BY se_keyword
ORDER BY Distinct_Visitors DESC
```

This will show all the keywords with unique visitors against the search keyword. But I want to show only the top keywords based on unique visitor that will cover 50% of total unique visitor.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem.  One method is the following:

- Reduce the data to one row per user and keyword (not necessary if there are no duplicates).
- Calculate a running total of the number of duplicates using `count(distinct)` as a window function.
- Filter for the conditions you want.

Here is what the logic looks like:

```
select distinct ku.keyword, ku.running_num_users
from (select ku.*,
             count(distinct userid) over (order by num_users desc) as running_num_users,
             count(distinct userid) as num_users_overall
      from (select keyword, userid,
                   count(*) over (partition by keyword) as num_users
            from t
            group by keyword, userid
           ) ku
     ) ku
where running_num_users <= 0.5 * num_users_overall;
```

Note that not all databases support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  There are simple workarounds, however.